# Apache Solr 5.0.0 Port 8983 Connection timed out

Tags: apache, azure, solr

I have successfully installed Apache Solr using terminal on the remote server (Ubuntu 14.04 on Windows Azure Servers). The status of Solr when checked using Terminal is listening on Port 8983 Happy Searching. But when I open http://MyIPAddress:8983/solr the connections gets timed out. Am I  missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened the port? By default only port 22 is open for SSH and the other ports are closed by a firewall.

To open ports, go to the Windows Azure management console. Click on "Virtual Machines" choose your VM, and click on "Endpoints" at the top. Click on "Add Endpoint", and fill in the details: protocol (TCP/UDP), public port (8983), and private port (8983).

Comment: Yes, I have opened it. But it's still not working. The same network timed out error shows up again.